# How to create api for client from separate file using express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to nodejs,I want to handle all routes and api from app/routes.js , I have router that i am using to get and post for the client. I dont see any response from server to client with below code, Any idea ?

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('./app/io').initialize(server);
var ditconsumer = require('./app/consumers/ditconsumer');

ditconsumer.start(server);
server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    //stconsumer.start();
});
```

app/routes.js

```
var express  = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var dirDirectory = require('./app/serverfiles/ditDir');

module.exports = function(app){

   router.get('/getAllFiles',function(req,res){
    dirDirectory.readDirectory(function(logFiles){
        res.json(logFiles);
        console.log(logFiles);
    });
});

    //other routes..
}
```

Comment: Where's your `app.use(router)`?

Comment: not sure where i suppose to add `app.use(router)`

Comment: In `app/routes.js`, most likely. See https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router. Edit: Also I don't see `app/routes` being imported from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so here is what you have done wrong

1. you have not require route app/route and use it as middleware
2. **You must export router in app/routes.js**

here is your changed code please try it and me know if it helped

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var myroute=require('./app/routes.js');
app.use(myroute);
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('./app/io').initialize(server);
var ditconsumer = require('./app/consumers/ditconsumer');

ditconsumer.start(server);
server.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
//stconsumer.start();
 });
```

app/routes.js

```
 var express  = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var dirDirectory = require('./app/serverfiles/ditDir');


router.get('/getAllFiles',function(req,res){
  dirDirectory.readDirectory(function(logFiles){
      res.json(logFiles);
       console.log(logFiles);
  });   
 });
 module.exports=router;  
   //other routes..
  }
```

please do let me know if this solves your problem